# Is It Possible To Get The Key From The React Route To Be Pass In Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My goals is to have edit form and add form, Now my problem is when I click on "Edit" button, it successfully displayed but when come to press on "Add New" button it render the previous data.

Currently, I am trying to have separate routes but in same component for add/edit forms in my react app like the below:

```
 <>
    <Switch>
        <Route key="add" path={`${match.url}/new`} component={AgenciesUpdatePage} />
        <Route key="edit" path={`${match.url}/:id/edit`} component={AgenciesUpdatePage} />
        <Route path={`${match.url}/:id`} component={AgenciesViewPage} />
        <Route path={match.url} component={AgenciesListPage} />
    </Switch>
</>
```

How do I get the (key) to be pass on my component because from my understanding the key is necessary to differentiate between two path for same component.

Else if you have other solution, I would like to check out.

Comment: `key` isn't a [route prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props), but is rather a reserved react prop used when rendering lists. Looks like you could examine the `match` or `location` prop to determine add/edit though. You could also add a query parameter, i.e. `?mode=edit` or similar.

Comment: can i have access to that key? or do you have any solution for my problem?

Comment: What are you really trying to use the `key` for? Having all these routes render the same component is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `key` prop in your route is for component mapping. The `AgenciesUpdatePage` won't be able to access its value using your current implementation.

Change your routes to the following:

```
<Route path={`${match.url}/new`} component={() => <AgenciesUpdatePage action="add" />} />
<Route path={`${match.url}/:id/edit`} component={() => <AgenciesUpdatePage action="edit" />} />
```

Then update your `AgenciesUpdatePage` component to use your newly implemented `action` prop.

You'll be able to access it in your `AgenciesUpdatePage` using something like this:

```
const AgenciesUpdatePage = ({ action }) => {
  if (action === 'add') // Render or do something
  if (action === 'edit') // Render or do something

  return (...)
}
```

Comment: I got this error instead
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: That's a problem with your `AgenciesUpdatePage` component. Not related to the problem your question addresses.